# Inequality with cyclic sum

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, radicals, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

**If $a+b+c=abc$, prove that
$\displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+1}} \leqslant \dfrac{3}{2}$.**

Comment: I'm not getting what's the meaning of *cyc*

Comment: from where does it come?

Comment: Let $a=\tan A, b=\tan B, c=\tan C$

Comment: set $$a=\tan(x),b=\tan(y),c=\tan(z)$$

Comment: @Daniel It means $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+1}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+1}}$.

Comment: @knm Thanks! is it standard? it seems I'm the only one who didn't get it

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it's very useful, but at Mathematical Olympiads, like JBMO, it's not often used (I think so ...) .

Answer (score 3):

By AM-GM
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+\frac{abc}{a+b+c}}}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}{a(a^2+ab+ac+bc)}}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{bc}{(a+b)(a+c)}}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{b}{a+b}+\frac{c}{a+c}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{b}{a+b}+\frac{a}{b+a}\right)=\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: nice prove Michael

Answer (score 1):

it is equivalent to $$\cos(x)+\cos(y)+\cos(z)\le \frac{3}{2}$$ which is true for $$x,y,z$$ angles in a triangle

Comment: Can we see a proof of the inequality $ \cos x+\cos y+\cos z \leqslant \dfrac{3}{2}$ ?

Comment: we have $$\cos(x)+\cos(y)+\cos(z)=1+\frac{r}{R}$$ and $$1+\frac{r}{R}\le \frac{3}{2}$$ since $$2r\le R$$